# Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController' not found

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, customer, php-5.4

I'm new to magento. here I have created custom module to add custom tab on customer information in `admin panel`. for that I have written following code. but it's returning an error. Any how here I'm not creating field to save the creditlimit attribute i will create after it's working.

**Error:
 Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController' not found.**

**my code is**:

**magento\app\etc\modules\Easylife_CreditLimit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_CreditLimit>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Easylife_CreditLimit>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Tab.php**

```
<?php
class Easylife_CreditLimit_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Tab
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface

{
    /**
     * Set the template for the block
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('creditlimit/customer/tab.phtml');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('My Custom Tab');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Click here to view your custom tab content');
    }
    /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tabs.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_CreditLimit_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {

        $this->addTab('Custom',array(
            'label' =>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Custom'),
            'class' =>   'ajax',
            'url'   =>   $this->getUrl('*/*/custom',array('_current'=>true)),
        ));
      return  parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    protected function _updateActiveTab()
    {
        parent::_updateActiveTab();
    }

}
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\Custom.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_CreditLimit_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('creditlimit/customer/tab/custom.phtml');
    }    

}
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomerController.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_CreditLimit_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController
{

    public function customAction()
    {
        $this->_initCustomer();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('creditlimit/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom','admin.customer.custom')->setCustomerId(Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
                ->setUseAjax(true)->toHtml());
    }

}
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_CreditLimit>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Easylife_CreditLimit>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <creditlimit before="Mage_Adminhtml">Easylife_CreditLimit_Adminhtml</creditlimit>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <creditlimit>
                    <file>creditlimit.xml</file>
                </creditlimit>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <creditlimit>
                <class>Easylife_CreditLimit_Block</class>
            </creditlimit>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <creditlimit>
                <class>Easylife_CreditLimit_Helper</class>
            </creditlimit>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
                <observers>
                    <creditlimit>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Easylife_CreditLimit_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>InjectTab</method>
                    </creditlimit>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
        </events>
    </global>

</config>
```

**magento\app\code\local\Easylife\CreditLimit\Model\Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_CreditLimit_Model_Observer
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }


    public function InjectTab(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        // add tab in customer edit page
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs)
        {
            if ($this->_getRequest()->getActionName() == 'edit' || $this->_getRequest()->getParam('type'))
            {
                $block->addTab('domains', array('label'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Manage Licensed Domains'),'url'=> $block->getUrl('*/*/custom', array('_current' => true)),'class'=> 'ajax'));
            }
        }

    }

    protected function _getRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest();
    }


}
```

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\easylife\layout\creditlimit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>my_custom_tab</name>
                <block>creditlimit/adminhtml_customer_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>

</layout>
```

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\easylife\template\creditlimit\customer\tab.phtml**

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" />
</div>
```

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\easylife\template\creditlimit\customer\tab\custom.phtml**

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label>Hi</label>

</div>
```

Can you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seams like a legit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controllers are not autoloaded, so this is why you get an error.
You need to load the controller with:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'CustomerController.php';

class Easylife_CreditLimit_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController {
...
}
```

Anyway, it's not the best to rewrite the Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController, better use event-dispatching and observer for your actions or create your own controller:

```
class Easylife_CreditLimit_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
...
}
```

See also here: [Trying to override a controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/trying-to-override-a-controller)