# What would be the proper way to overwrite returnAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

I am trying to extend default PayPal Express functionality.
I have successfully rewritten `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` like

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <paypalexpressconfirmation>
                <class>Namespace_PayPalExpressConfirmation_Model</class>
            </paypalexpressconfirmation>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Namespace_PayPalExpressConfirmation_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </models>
 </global>
```

But cannot find the way to overwrite

```
public function returnAction()
{
    try {
        $this->_initCheckout();
        $this->_checkout->returnFromPaypal($this->_initToken());
        $this->_redirect('*/*/placeOrder');
        return;
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('Unable to process Express Checkout approval.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`

I have tried using an observer in the event controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_return and its triggered when customer come back from PayPal page but I don't see anything that allows me to intercept this method and rewrite it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot overwrite an Abstract class.

Instead we can achieve what we want by overwriting

```
Mage_Paypal_ExpressController` controller
```

There we can overwrite the method(s).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<config>
<.......>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <paypal>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Paypal before="Mage_Paypal">Namespace_Paypal</Namespace_Paypal>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </paypal>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
<.......>
</config>
```

Now copy Abstract.php from core folder to `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php`

Edit this file in the following way.

```
require_once("Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php");

abstract class Namespace_Paypal_Express_Abstract extends Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract
{
     public function returnAction()
    {
        //your custom code
    }
}
```

I've not been able to test the code, so please let me know if it works.

Please refer to the following link to override a controller

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Thanks

Comment: Please can you put the relevant code as the answer. Then refer to the link. If the link becomes stale, the answer will be pointless in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there should be a more optimal way to handle this. Perhaps using controller dispatch events like @philwinkle recommend in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/trying-to-override-a-controller