# issue in block rendering and product review post action rewriting

Tags: magento-1.6

I am creating captcha for product review form. For that I have faced two problem.

First I tried to rewrite post action url, using this code in `config.xml`.

```
<rewrite>
            <namespace_module>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/review/product/post/#]]></from>
                <to>/module/review/post/</to>
            </namespace_module>
</rewrite>
```

this code is not working. when I submit form it redirect me to homepage.

Second issue is that, I am trying to add block on just above submit button using this code.

in `base/default/layout/namespace_module.xml`

```
<review_product_list>
        <block name="product.review.form" >
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" template="namespace/module/form.phtml"/>
        </block>
</review_product_list>
```

in `base/default/template/review/form.phtml`

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_block');
```

This code is also not working. 
Do you have idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the layout XML, the alias (`as="..."`) is missing, which is necessary to reference the block with `getChildHtml()`:

```
<block type="core/template" name="custom_block"
    template="namespace/module/form.phtml" as="custom_block" />
```

The `rewrite` syntax for controllers is very outdated and should not be used anymore, even in Magento 1.6.

For rewriting controllers or adding functionality, see: [Trying to override a controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/trying-to-override-a-controller)